# Podcast Management Web / Android

Tags: android, podcast

I usually listen to/watch podcasts on my Android devices, but I would like to be able to manage them from a web browser or perhaps desktop app.

This probably means an account in the cloud which stores the information, and which is accessible from an Android app, and with a web interface.

Ideally it should be possible to click links, like with iTunes, or past links from the web.

Answer (score 1):

[gPodder](http://gpodder.org/) is a free, synchronizing podcast fetcher/client which can not only sync subscriptions but even until which position you've already listened an episode.

It's available for Linux, FreeBSD, Windows, Mac OS X, the Nokia N9, Blackberry 10, the Blackberry Playbook, Sailfish OS and Android.

If you use their [gpodder.net](https://gpodder.net/) service or if you install the according [web application](https://github.com/gpodder/mygpo) on your web server, you can also manage your subscriptions in your web browser.

Comment: gPodder on Android doesn't seems to powerful, and the only full-feature Android client on their list is is PAY (OK, but should be mentioned).

Comment: How could is the selection of podcasts?  Do Windows clients work like iTunes replacements?

Answer (score 1):

[Pocket Casts](http://www.shiftyjelly.com/pocketcasts) should fit in your needs. It's a cross platform podcast app with a Web interface to manage your subscriptions and backups.

Comment: It seems to be PAY (perhaps only browser interface?)

Comment: @Olav yeah, it's an app that you need to buy. If you want a free option, please mention this in your question as a requirement.

Comment: I just think it should be mentioned (Actually I was thinking of the web interface, I had forgotten about the app).